# How to call multiple modules inside a single module on nestJS?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm building an API that will act as a gateway to connect 2 services, `company-order` and `partner-order`, each one with his specific URL host, timeout and etc, on my application I've added a single controller that will call `company-order` API and send the data to `partner-order` API, the modules organization looks like this:

```
- company/
    - company-http-config.service.ts
    - company-order.service.ts
    - company.module.ts
- partner/
    - partner-http-config.service.ts
    - partner-order.service.ts
    - partner.module.ts
- orders/
    - orders.controller.ts
    - orders.module.ts
```

Each module has his own `HttpModule` configuration declared at the `.module.ts` file;

```
// company.module.ts
imports: [
    HttpModule.registerAsync({
        useClass: CompanyHttpConfig,
    }),
]

// partner.module.ts
imports: [
    HttpModule.registerAsync({
        useClass: PartnerHttpConfig,
    }),
]
```

Each service import their `HttpService` to use their respective `HttpConfig` class:

```
// partner-order.service.ts
export class PartnerOrderService {
    construct(private readonly http: HttpService) {}
}


// company-order.service.ts
export class CompanyOrderService {
    construct(private readonly http: HttpService) {}
}
```

In order to use both services on the `order` module, I've to import both `http-config` into my `order` module, or I'll get an error saying that I need to import the `HttpService` class.

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PartnerOrderService (?). Please make sure that the argument HttpService at index [0] is available in the OrderModule context.

I can import the `HttpService` on the `OrderModule`:

```
imports: [
    HttpModule.registerAsync({
        useClass: PartnerHttpConfigService,
    }),
]
```

But now I need to also import the `CompanyOrderService` into `OrderModule` and define the `HttpService` as well, but if I do this the `HttpModule` will be duplicated on `OrderModule` imports key.

How can I import two distinct modules into a single module with separated `Http` configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CompanyOrderModule` should have the `HttpModule.register()` in its `imports` with the specific configuration needed and the `CompanyOrderService`  in both the `providers` and `exports` arrays.

Now your `OrderModule` should have the`CompanyOrderModule` and the `HttpModule.register(orderConfig)` in the `imports` array and only the `OrderService` in the `providers` array.

Because the `CompanyOrderModule` `exports` the `CompanyOrderService` the `OrderService` has access to inject the `CompanyOrderService` without your `OrderModule` having to re-declare the re-configure the provider

---

A roughly configured example would look something like this

##### CompanyOrderModule

```js
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule.registerAsync({
    useClass: CompanyHttpConfig
  })],
  providers: [CompanyOrderService],
  exports: [CompanyOrderService],
})
export class CompanyOrderModule {}
```

##### PartnerOrderModule

```js
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule.registerAsync({
    useClass: PartnerHttpConfig
  })],
  providers: [PartnerOrderService],
  exports: [PartnerOrderService],
})
export class PartnerOrderModule {}
```

##### OrderModule

```js
@Module({
  imports: [CompanyOrderModule, PartnerOrderModule],
  providers: [OrderService],
  controllers: [OrderController],
})
export class OrderModule {}
```

##### OrderController

```js
@Controller()
export class OrderController {
  constructor(
    private readonly orderService: OrderService,
    private readonly companyOrderService: CompanyOrderService,
    private readonly partnerOrderService: PartnerOrderService,
  ) {}

  @Get('/example1')
  public example1() {
    return this.partnerOrderService.doSomething();
  }

  @Get('/example2')
  public example2() {
    return this.companyOrderService.doSomething();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you give some example on how to use both `CompanyOrderService` and `PartnerOrderService` on `Order` module?

Comment: @RafaAcioly I've added what the module configuration most likely should look like

Comment: After adding these modules' on the `OrderModule` my application stopped mapping the controllers.

Comment: @RafaAcioly Added an example of how to use the imported services in the OrderModule, in this example I've used the OrderController, but you can use inside a service too.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel the `OrderModule` is exactly how you answered, I imported the CompanyOrderModule, PartnerOrderModule into the `imports` key and added the `OrderController` on the `controllers` key

Comment: here's the source code; https://github.com/rafa-acioly/gateway-poc

Comment: @RafaAcioly Line 18 of the Company Http Config Service, how do you pan to inject the HttpService into this class when this class is what should be getting its configuration?

Comment: Yeah, just tried replacing the `HttpService` in your `CompanyHttpConfigService` with `axios` directly and got things to keep moving on to an error due to an invalid API token (or non-existent in my case). Circular dependencies like that are able to halt the application if things somehow go incredibly wrong, just so you know, so I'd highly suggest avoiding that