# NestJS not mapping controllers

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to import some controllers on `app.module.ts` but they are not being mapped after the application starts.

main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('My Gateway')
    .setDescription('API to connect to my services')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .build();

  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    OrderModule,
    ProductModule,
    CacheModule.register({ isGlobal: true }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When I run `npm run start:dev` all dependencies are loaded except by the controllers

```
LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +0ms
LOG [InstanceLoader] ProductModule dependencies initialized +0ms
LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
LOG [InstanceLoader] HttpModule dependencies initialized +1ms
```

On `ProductModule` and `OrderModule` I've also imported the controllers

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [OrderController],
  providers: [OrderService],
  exports: [OrderService],
})
export class OrderModule {}
```

Each controller also have the `@Controller` decorator declaraded.

How can I include my controllers to be mapped and start accepting requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As I've mentioned on your other question in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75879222/how-to-call-multiple-modules-inside-a-single-module-on-nestjs/75879317?noredirect=1#comment133856611_75879317) what's happening is that your `CompanyHttpConfigService` depends on the `HttpService` which it is trying to create the configuration for, and Nest isn't reporting the circular dependency for some reason, even though one exists, probably due to swallowing an error somewhere. Change out the `HttpService` for raw `axios` in that configuration and you should be good to keep developing.

Answer (score 0):

##### ORIGINAL

Your controllers are tagged with de @Controller decorator?

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('orders')
export class OrdersController {
  @Get()
  findAll(): string {
    return 'This action returns all orders';
  }
}
```

##### EDIT 1

This is a one file code to reproduce a working route in NestJS:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Controller, Get, Injectable, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class OrdersService {
  public doSomething() {
    return [{ foo: 'bar' }];
  }
}

@Controller()
export class OrdersController {
  constructor(private readonly ordersService: OrdersService) {}

  @Get()
  public getOrders() {
    return this.ordersService.doSomething();
  }
}

@Module({
  controllers: [OrdersController],
  providers: [OrdersService],
})
export class OrdersModule {}

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot(), OrdersModule],
})
export class AppModule {}

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Running `npm run start:dev` you should see in your terminal:

```bash
[Nest] 63969  - 03/29/2023, 10:55:54 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 63969  - 03/29/2023, 10:55:54 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +7ms
[Nest] 63969  - 03/29/2023, 10:55:54 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 63969  - 03/29/2023, 10:55:54 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] OrdersModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 63969  - 03/29/2023, 10:55:54 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 63969  - 03/29/2023, 10:55:54 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] OrdersController {/}: +5ms
[Nest] 63969  - 03/29/2023, 10:55:54 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 63969  - 03/29/2023, 10:55:54 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +2ms
```

Comment: yes, I've added decorator on both controllers

Comment: @RafaAcioly Added a working example

Comment: Earlier today I post this question and after applying it to my code the controller stopped to be mapped; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75879222/how-to-call-multiple-modules-inside-a-single-module-on-nestjs/75879317

Comment: The answer looks great, all you need to do to use the imported services is add the needed service in the constructor of the controller or the service that should use.

constructor (private readonly partnerOrderService: PartnerOrderService) {}
...
this.partnerOrderService.

Do you have a repository with the problem?

Comment: Yes, here it is https://github.com/rafa-acioly/gateway-poc

Comment: @RafaAcioly
Good afternoon Rafael! About your problem. The issue is occurring for this reason:
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/8894

In the "company-http-config.service.ts" file that is trying to inject "httpService" (Line 25) even before it was created (Since HttpModuleOptionsFactory is the HttpModules creation factory). Replace this dependency injection with a pure axios or fetch.

Comment: Added one example of solution: https://github.com/rafa-acioly/gateway-poc/issues/1